# Busqueda de resultados desde Form secundario

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagridview

Tengo un ABM de Piezas que abre automáticamente un segundo form para realizar búsquedas con filtros.

Si no se inputa ninguna valor, buscará sin filtros y volcara en un Data Grid.

Esto hace mi boton "Buscar":

```
private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtCodigo.Text != "")
        {
            string codigo = txtCodigo.Text;
            frmPiezas.llenarGridPiezasConFiltros(codigo);
        }
        else { frmPiezas.llenarGridPiezasSinFiltros(); }
        this.Close();
    }
```

Mas adelante, se ejecuta la sentencia, no da errores pero en el Grid no se ven resultados.

Sin embargo, si ejecuto "llenarGridPiezasConFiltros()" o "llenarGridPiezasSinFiltros()" desde el primer form, funciona y llena la Grid.

¿Por que ejecutada la función desde otro Form no funciona?

Comment: Entiendo que tenes form1 y form2, estas intentando que desde form2 cuando usas el filtro, en form1 se actualice el grid?

Answer (score 0):

si frmPiezas es tu formulario donde muestras las piezas;  lo que veo en el código es que te falta la instrucción frmPiezas.Show(); para mostrar el formulario.

Answer (score 0):

Exactamente así es.

Pude solucionar el problema. 
Estaba creando un nuevo objeto Form en vez de utilizar el que ya tenía. Por eso cuando llenaba la grilla lo hacía en un nuevo objeto.. y no en el que ya tenía instanciado